# Compiler does't recognize overloaded method in another method

Tags: c++, string, overloading

I have two classes: "Station" which has method getName() returning string and "Profit" which has the overloaded method sellAt(string stName), sellAt(Station st). To avoid duplicate code I call sellAt(string stName) in sellAt(string stName), however in some cases (see code example below) compiler gives an error: "no instance of overloaded function "Profit::SellAt" matches the argument list. Argument types are: (std::string)". Is it a bug or I miss something?

**Station.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Station
{
private:
    string sName;
public:
    Station(string name);
    string getName();
};
```

**Station.cpp**

```
#include "Station.h"

Station::Station(string name)
    :sName(name)
{}

string Station::getName()
{
    return sName;
}
```

**Profit.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Station.h"
#include <string>

class Profit
{
public:
    double SellAt(string& stName);
    double SellAt(Station& st);
};
```

**Profit.cpp**

```
#include "Profit.h"

double Profit::SellAt(const string& stName)
{
    // do stuff
}

// Works as expected
double Profit::SellAt(Station& st)
{
    string stName = st.getName();
    return SellAt(stName);
}

// Compile error
double Profit::SellAt(Station& st)
{
    return SellAt(st.getName());
}

// Compile error
double Profit::SellAt(Station& st)
{
    double result = SellAt(st.getName());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Your code compiles.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OkM3sxnx9WKky3hS) What `Station::getName()` returns looks important. Again, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `st.getName()` is a temporary. You cannot bind non-const reference to a temporary. I suppose you shouldn't want to modify `stName` in `Profit::SellAt()`, so change the type of argument to `const std::string&`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank You! That explains the issue.

Comment: @MikeCAT Added reproducible example. In your test getName() (line 6) returns a reference to name instead of its copy, hence test runs successfully. It also means that internal parameter of Station is directly accessible from the ouside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yksisarvinen answered in the comment below the original question:

> st.getName() is a temporary. You cannot bind non-const reference to a temporary. I suppose you shouldn't want to modify stName in Profit::SellAt(), so change the type of argument to const std::string&.

Thanks for the help!